# Index of the subgroup $\langle l \rangle $ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n)^\times$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $l,p $ be distinct primes, let $g(n)$ be the index of the subgroup $\langle l \rangle $ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n)^\times$. Then will this $g(n)$ increase? Will it stabilize (I guess so)? If so what's the limit explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $p$ is odd. Typically $g(n)$ is constant. In general, there exists $k\ge1$ such that $g(n)=pg(n-1)$ for $1<n\le k$, and $g(n)=g(n-1)$ for $n\ge k$. (The $k=1$ case is when $g$ is constant.)

To prove this, let $h=(p-1)/g(1)$ be the order of $l$ modulo $p$, so that $p$ divides $l^h-1$. Write $l^h-1 = p^km$ with $p\nmid m$. Then you can prove that the order of $l$ modulo $p^n$ is $h$ when $n\le k$ and $hp^{n-k}$ when $n>k$. Hint:
$$
l^{hb}-1 = (l^h-1)(l^{h(b-1)}+l^{h(b-2)}+\cdots+l^{2h}+l^h+1),
$$
and each summand in the second factor is congruent to $1$ modulo $p^k$, hence $1$ modulo $p$. (In the $k=1$ case, to show that we don't pick up additional factors of $p$ from the second factor when $b=p$, write $l^h\equiv 1+tp\pmod{p^2}$ and show that the second factor is $\equiv p\pmod{p^2}$ independent of $t$.)